# missing parenthesis error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this function:

```
function sel_test(e) {
  //alert(e.length-1);

  var splitdata = e.split("d");
  var newstr = e.substring(0,e.length-1);

  dropcall = 1;
  nodes = newstr.split(';');
  o = 0;
  if (nodes[0] == '1') o = nodes.shift();
  for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
    e = nodes[i];
    var ul = document.getElementById(e);
    if (icons) var img = document.getElementById(e+'i');
    if (ul) {
      if (((ul == 'none') AND (ul.style.display == 'none')) OR (ul.style.display == '')) {
        ul.style.display = 'block';
      } else if (!o) {
        ul.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
```

javascript is giving me an error of missing parenthesis:

`if (((ul == 'none') AND (ul.style.display == 'none')) OR (ul.style.display == '')) {`

what this the correct way of doing this.

Comment: If you don't get syntax errors from "AND" and "OR", then you must have a different version of javascript than I do.

Comment: Are AND and OR invalid identifiers?

Comment: @zhujy_8833: They're valid identifiers, but invalid operators, so even if they were defined as identifiers that could be resolved, JS would be looking for a semicolon to separate the statements.

Comment: Even after your edit, you're still missing the final right squiggly bracket to close the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using && and || instead of AND and OR.

Shouldn't you?

Comment: if i using && perl thows an error, adding inside an perl file

Comment: I thought you said this was javascript?

Comment: can you please post your answer instead of making a question?

Comment: You said this was javascript. (for the benefit of @Daniele B)

Comment: I meant in your answer not in the comment (which I even upvoted). Nothing against you. But it's not nice to see a question where it is supposed to have an answer.

Comment: BTW @Daniele B, I tried to get in an answer on your fun question, but it was closed too quickly. I wanted to say that down voting and closing questions seem to be fun for many.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (((ul == 'none') && (ul.style.display == 'none')) || (ul.style.display == ''))
```

JavaScript has an AND operator, but it isn't the word `AND`, it is `&&` (also `&`, for a bitwise and). Similarly, rather than `OR` you want `||` (or `|` for bitwise).

Note that your `ul` variable will *never* be equal to the string `'none'` - the return from `document.getElementById(e)` will always be either the matching DOM element, or `null` if no element has the supplied id.

Further reading: [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) (and you *should* read it, because `&&` and `||` don't always return `true` or `false` and MDN explains this).

Answer (score 0):

You are also missing the closing right squiggly for the function.

Comment: In addition, eclipse tells me that splitdata and img are never read, and i is not explicitly declared.

Comment: forget about splitdata, iam not using that

Comment: forgotten -- it's like I never saw it

Comment: The comment string had gotten so long on my other answer that I thought this deserved an answer of its own so that it wouldn't be missed.